# Count number of items in NSArray with certain property (iPhone Programming)

Tags: iphone

I have an NSArray that looks like this:

```
ArrayItem *thisone = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name" data1:@"Some data" data2:@"Some more data" image:@"theimage.jpg" range:0];

ArrayItem *thisone1 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name" data1:@"Some data" data2:@"Some more data" image:@"theimage.jpg" range:0];

ArrayItem *thisoneagain = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 2" data1:@"Some data2" data2:@"Some more data2" image:@"theimage2.jpg" range:1];

ArrayItem *thisoneagain1 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 2" data1:@"Some data2" data2:@"Some more data2" image:@"theimage2.jpg" range:1];

ArrayItem *thisoneagain2 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 2" data1:@"Some data2" data2:@"Some more data2" image:@"theimage2.jpg" range:1];

ArrayItem *thisoneyetagain = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 3" data1:@"Some data3" data2:@"Some more data3" image:@"theimage3.jpg" range:2];

ArrayItem *thisoneyetagain1 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 3" data1:@"Some data3" data2:@"Some more data3" image:@"theimage3.jpg" range:2];

ArrayItem *thisoneyetagain2 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 3" data1:@"Some data3" data2:@"Some more data3" image:@"theimage3.jpg" range:2];

ArrayItem *thisoneyetagain3 = [[ArrayItem alloc] initWithName:@"The Name 3" data1:@"Some data3" data2:@"Some more data3" image:@"theimage3.jpg" range:2];

self.ArrayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:thisone,thisone1,thisoneagain,thisoneagain1,thisoneagain2,thisoneyetagain,thisoneyetagain1,thisoneyetagain2,thisoneyetagain3,nil];
```

and I would like to count the number of items in each "range" (as in there are 2 items with a range of 0, 3 with a range of 1, and 4 with a range of 2) and store the number of items for each range in separate variables. Any idea how to do this? ArrayItems.count just tells me how many there are in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a general programming question rather than iOS specific, but I will give you the answer using Objective-C.

After you create your array you can do the following:

```
int range0=0;
int range1=0;
int range2=0;    
for (ArrayItem* item in self.ArrayItems) {
//Assuming range is an int property of ArrayItem we can switch on it.
    switch (item.range) {
        case 0:
            range0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            range2++;
            break;
        case 2:
            range3++
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This will give you the numer of items on each range stored on the range0, range1 and range2 variables.

Using Tim's Approach you can do something like this:

```
NSUInteger counts[3] = {0,0,0};
for(ArrayItem * item in self.ArrayItems) {
    counts[item.range]++;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it just tells me "Array subscript is not an integer", even though it is declared as one?

Comment: I figured my above problem out, I was using a pointer where I shouldn't have been, which mucked it up. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using blocks, starting from iOS 4:

```
NSIndexSet *range0Indexes = [self.ArrayItems indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL)^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   return ((ArrayItem *)obj).range == 0;
}];

NSUInteger countRange0 = [range0Indexes count];

do same for range1 and range2.
```

Comment: I'm using the 3.1.3 SDK (i know its old but I'm stuck on OS X 10.5.8 and can't get the latest) so I can't use that, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
NSUInteger counts[3] = {0,0,0};
for(ArrayItem * item in self.ArrayItems) {
    counts[item.range]++;
}
```

Then `counts[i]` has the number of items in your array with range `i`. (It helps greatly that your ranges start at zero and are (presumably) integers.)

Comment: foreach is not a valid function on Objective-C (C99) but I like the use of an array to store the values instead of different variables. It is easier to extend. I will update my answer to use your approach.

Comment: @Zebs: my bad, I was thinking the `foreach` (fast enumeration) concept but in ObjC the syntax just uses the `for` keyword. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The ranges are integers, and they do start at zero, but I keep getting the error "array subscript is not an integer" at the "counts[item.range]++;" line, even though it is declared as one?